# Importing .jars and validate the classes for all other users

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have 35 .jar files I need to import, before I can use my Java Source class in Oracle. I executed this command for every 35 .jars as SYSDBA:

```
call dbms_java.loadjava('-genmissing -r -v -force -grant MYSCHEMA ./first-jar-file.jar');
```

The problem is, that if I switch to the main (non SYSDBA) user, the classes are invalid. What can I do about it? So, my question is: how can I import these files and get the java classes valid for all other users?

EDIT.: If I check the invalid Java classes as SYSDBA after the import:

```
 SELECT * FROM user_objects
 WHERE object_type like '%JAVA%'
 AND status = 'INVALID'
```

The result is approx. 10 invalid classes (not relevant). After I switch to the other user and execute the same query, the invalid class number is near 500...

Thank you very much!

Comment: What type error do you get?

Comment: ORA-29521: referenced name XYZ/XXYY could not be found

Comment: But xyz/xxyy is  com/mycompany  or oracle/aurora ?

Comment: com/mycompany, not oracle/aurora

Comment: try to resolve each class `alter java class "class_name" resolve;`